# how to group/combine aggregated dataframe elements from multiple dataframes into a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single data set that I've broken into two grouped dataframes with identical columns and rows, only the values differ. Each is aggregated differently. DataFrame x1 is "counted"; and DataFrame x2 is "summed".

This is the groupby code I wrote to breakout/group the data set:

```
x1 = DATA.groupby('PP')[ x, y ,z ].count()  
      - (the same code is used for x2, except instead of ".count()" I did ".sum()".
```

After both sets were built individually, I use the .merge : "x3 = pd.merge(x1,x2, on='PP', how= 'right', right_index = False).transpose()"
- transpose for making the vertical structure

This works, the column is "PP" as i wanted, however the rows are not grouped as I wanted, it looks like this:

```
PP  PP  PP  PP  PP
1   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x
3   x   x   x   x
1   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x
3   x   x   x   x
```

I need

```
PP  PP  PP  PP  PP
1   x   x   x   x
1   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x
3   x   x   x   x
3   x   x   x   x
```

I need the rows with the same identifiers to be grouped with the "PP" as the running index for each column.

any ideas are most welcome!

Comment: Did you try sort_index? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did try the sort_index, but it didn't work for what I needed. I am extremely new to python...and apologize for the simplistic questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you put x instead of showing the values, it is hard to understand what you're trying to do, but one thing I would try is remove the `left_index=False` and put instead `left_index=True, right_index=True`.
Of course I am assuming here that the colored column is your index.

Alternatively, you can create a new data frame where the columns are x1, x2, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The x in place of the actual values were purposeful in that it's not the values, but the formatting that I need help with. I tried the dual indexing as you suggested, and it resulted in negating the values from one dataframe or the other. The format remained the same. .

Comment: Have you tried adding an argument ' how="outer" ' to the merge method?

Comment: i did, however it negatively created all kinds of null values. I shifted gears and tried:
x4 = pd.concat([x1, x2]).groupby('PP_APPLIED', as_index=True).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1)).reset_index(drop=True).transpose()
#DATA.rename(columns={'Sick Leave': 'Sick_Leave' , 'Annual Leave':'Annual_Leave','Weather & Safety Leave': 'Weather_&_Safety_Leave'}, inplace = True)
#x4.reset_index()
x4.rename(columns={0:'Count', 1:'Sum', 2:'Count', 3:'Sum', 4:'Count', 5:'Sum', 6:'Count', 7:'Sum',8:'Count'
                   , 9:'Sum',10:'Count', 11:'Sum',12:'Count', 13:'Sum'}, inplace = True)